# adding a scroll bar to my description text

Tags: css

[Output Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RUsa.png)

[So far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/875mp.png)

Main.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <title>Canada</title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/normalize.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/site.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
      <header>
      <h1>Canadian Provinces and Territories</h1>
        <div id="logo"> <img class="flag" src="images/Canada.png" alt="Canada"> Canada</div>
      </header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberta">Alberta</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Columbia">British Columbia</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manitoba">Manitoba</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Brunswick">New Brunswick</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_and_Labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_Scotia">Nova Scotia</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Territories">Northwest Territories</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nunavut">Nunavut</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontario">Ontario</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Edward_Island">Prince Edward Island</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec">Quebec</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</a></li>
          <li> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukon">Yukon</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

      <section class="main">

        <div class="province" id="AB"> <img class="flag" src="images/Alberta.png" alt="Alberta"> 
          <div class="description">Alberta is Canada's fourth-most populous province and most populous of Canada's three prairie provinces. Alberta and its neighbour, Saskatchewan, were established...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberta">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="BC"> <img class="flag" src="images/British_Columbia.png" alt="British Columbia"> 
          <div class="description">British Columbia is also a component of the Pacific Northwest, along with the U.S. states of Oregon and Washington. The province's name was chosen by Queen...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Columbia">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="MB"> <img class="flag" src="images/Manitoba.png" alt="Manitoba"> 
          <div class="description">Manitoba is a Canadian prairie province. The province, with an area of 649,950 square kilometres (250,900 sq mi), has a largely continental climate, with...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manitoba">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="NB"> <img class="flag" src="images/New_Brunswick.png" alt="New Brunswick"> 
          <div class="description">New Brunswick is one of Canada's three Maritime provinces and is the only province in the Canadian federation that is constitutionally bilingual...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Brunswick">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="NL"> <img class="flag" src="images/Newfoundland_and_Labrador.png" alt="Newfoundland and Labrador"> 
          <div class="description">Newfoundland and Labrador is the most easterly province of Canada. Situated in the country's Atlantic region, it incorporates the island of Newfoundland... </div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_and_Labrador">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="NS"> <img class="flag" src="images/Nova_Scotia.png" alt="Nova Scotia"> 
          <div class="description">Nova Scotia is one of Canada's three Maritime provinces and constitutes one of the four Atlantic Canada provinces. Located almost exactly halfway between... </div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_Scotia">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="NT"> <img class="flag" src="images/Northwest_Territories.png" alt="Northwest Territories"> 
          <div class="description">The Northwest Territories is a territory of Canada. With a population of 43,537 in 2013, the Northwest Territories is the most populous territory in Northern...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Territories">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="NU"> <img class="flag" src="images/Nunavut.svg.png" alt="Nunavut"> 
          <div class="description">Nunavut is the largest, northernmost and newest territory of Canada. It was separated officially from the Northwest Territories on April 1, 1999, via the Nunavut...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nunavut">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="ON"> <img class="flag" src="images/Ontario.png" alt="Ontario"> 
          <div class="description">Ontario is one of the ten provinces of Canada, located in east-central Canada. It is Canada's most populous province by a large margin, accounting for nearly...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontario">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="PE"> <img class="flag" src="images/Prince_Edward_Island.png" alt="Prince Edward Island"> 
          <div class="description">Prince Edward Island (PEI or P.E.I.) is a Canadian province consisting of the main island itself, as well as other islands. It is one of the three Maritime ...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Edward_Island">Read more </a></div>
        <div class="province" id="QC"> <img class="flag" src="images/Quebec.png" alt="Quebec"> 
          <div class="description">Quebec is a province in east-central Canada. It is the only Canadian province that has a predominantly French-speaking population, and the only one to have...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="SK"> <img class="flag" src="images/Saskatchewan.png" alt="Saskatchewan"> 
        <div class="description">Saskatchewan (Listeni/səˈskætʃəwən/ or /səˈskætʃəˌwɑːn/) is a prairie province in Canada, which has a total area of 651,900 square kilometres (251,700 sq mi) and... </div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saskatchewan">Read more</a></div>
        <div class="province" id="YT"> <img class="flag" src="images/Yukon.png" alt="Yukon"> 
        <div class="description">Yukon is the westernmost and smallest of Canada's three federal territories. Whitehorse is the territorial capital and Yukon's only city. The territory was split from...</div>
          <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukon">Read more</a></div>
      </section>
  <footer>
    <script >       
          var dt=new Date(document.lastModified);   
          document.write('This page was last updated on '+dt.toLocaleString())      
    </script>
  </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Css

```
div.province.description
{
    max-height: 165px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

So I need to do

The element must not
be any higher than
165 pixels

• Only If the content goes beyond 165 pixels high, show a scroll bar

• If the content does not fit in the container horizontally, hide the scrollbar

• The top and bottom margins must be 8 pixels

but it doesn't seem to work for the scroll bar. is there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: *it doesn't seem to work for the scroll bar* learn to be more specific.

Comment: Can you put what you have on something like codepen.io so we can see what you've got?

Comment: So we're supposed to solve your problem based on the single CSS rule you posted. Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a space:

```
div.province.description
{
    max-height: 165px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

should be

```
div.province .description
{
    max-height: 165px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

div.province.description is a selector for a div containing both "province" and "description" classes.  You're trying to select the element with the class "description" contained within the div having "province" class.  Just add a space after the word "province" and you're good.  Don't know about the rest of your CSS, since it wasn't posted.

Also, you might try overflow-y:auto and it will only show the scroll bar if the content exceeds height, as you stipulate in your first bullet point.

Comment: Thanks so very much Sir. that's super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the content is every going over 165px, so the description never has the need to scroll anything. Perhaps try limiting the width of the `province` div. This will cause the text break more often and extend the height required to display it.